# Upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: upgrade

I have a bootable disk of 12.10 and currently system is running 12.04
I am looking for a method where I upgrade to 12.10 without loosing data by bootable disk

Answer (score 1):

If you boot your computer from the new Ubuntu 12.10 disk you should have an **Upgrade** option, but I prefer upgrading via **Software Updater**.